# Subresource integrity for animate.css?

Tags: animate.css, subresource-integrity

Google didn't turn up anything on the topic and there are some questions related to Subresource integrity on Stackoverflow but my question is: how do you generate this cryptographic hash for a CDN `<link>` ? In my case it is the animate.css, but I guess this can be applied to any custom CSS file.

Cheers

Comment: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/09/subresource-integrity-in-firefox-43/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SRIHash from Mozilla](https://www.srihash.org/)

Example using animate.css from JSDelivr

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/3.5.2/animate.min.css" 
      integrity="sha384-OHBBOqpYHNsIqQy8hL1U+8OXf9hH6QRxi0+EODezv82DfnZoV7qoHAZDwMwEJvSw" 
      crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Or you can generate it using your console :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity#Tools_for_generating_SRI_hashes